# In openpyxl, how to move or copy a cell range with formatting, merged cells, formulas and hyperlinks

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to move a cell range inside a worksheet using Python 2.7 + openpyxl. What seemed to be an easy and basic task turned out to be close to impossible. Here is how I'd like it to look in Excel:

[image: Excel copying pasting]

To make the task easier let's assume I only need to move range from given cell to the end of data (to last row and column). My first idea was easy:

```
for i, column in enumerate(columns):
    if i >= starting_col:
        for j, cell in enumerate(column):
            if j >= starting_row:
                copy_cell(ws, j+1, i+1, j+1, i+movement)
```

But hey, what how to efficiently and fully realize `copy_cell`?
By trial and error I managed to come to 4 things I need to copy:

1. Value
2. Style
3. Hyperlinks
4. Number format

It didn't work quite as I expected - most of cells are copied properly but hyperlinks don't seem to work, copying .style attribute didn't work either (hence my try to access _style which worked) and my worst problem appeared - merged cell ranged. How to deal with them? My `copy_cell()` looks like this at the moment:

```
def copy_cell(ws, from_row, from_col, to_row, to_col):
    # first value
    ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col).value = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col).value
    # second formatting
    from_style = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col)._style
    ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col)._style = from_style
    ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col).hyperlink = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col).hyperlink
    ws.cell(row=to_row, column=to_col).number_format = ws.cell(row=from_row, column=from_col).number_format
```

Isn't there a better, generic way to copy whole cell range? Or at least whole cell with all of its attributes? If not, maybe there is an efficient way to move or copy merged cell ranges?

Answer (score 2):

I have built this method to copy cells without touching their contents:

```
import copy

def move_cell(source_cell, dest_row, dest_col, preserve_original=False):
    """
    :param source_cell: cell to be moved to new coordinates
    :param dest_row: 1-indexed destination row
    :param dest_col: 1-indexed destination column
    :param preserve_original: if True, does a copy instead of a move
    """
    if preserve_original:
        cell_to_move = copy.copy(source_cell)
    else:
        cell_to_move = source_cell

    worksheet = cell_to_move.parent
    source_address = (cell_to_move.row, cell_to_move.col_idx)
    dest_address = (dest_row, dest_col)

    cell_to_move.row = dest_row
    cell_to_move.col_idx = dest_col
    worksheet._cells[dest_address] = cell_to_move
    if not preserve_original:
        del worksheet._cells[source_address]

    return cell_to_move
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use `deepcopy`

Comment: It's an old question but I remember struggling with `deepcopy`. It performs copy recursively and fails on one of the arrays inside the cell structure.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks for the pointer. So far I have not run into any issues, but will keep `deepcopy` in mind if any weird ones arise.

Comment: any idea on how to copy the merged cells

Comment: could you explain this with an example ? @KrystianCybulski I've got just errors :( function' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: It's been ages since I touched this code. It's possible that you are importing `copy` as `from copy import copy`. If that is the case, please modify `copy.copy(` to just `copy(`. I have updated the above example to make this more explicit.

Comment: @KrystianCybulski Thx. import copy is the solution for the attribute 'copy' error. Dont know this little thing. But if I use the script i get another error than :( 

<ipython-input-26-c8c6f5ce29ec> in move_cell(source_cell, dest_row, dest_col, preserve_original)
     29 
     30     cell_to_move.row = dest_row
---> 31     cell_to_move.col_idx = dest_col
     32     worksheet._cells[dest_address] = cell_to_move
     33     if not preserve_original:

AttributeError: can't set attribute

But i printed dest_col. dest_col = 1. I just want to copy one source row (5) to the row(6)

Comment: @KrystianCybulski do you have any idea ? :) dont find a fix for the problem

Comment: I'm sorry @Paddymaster, but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: I get `cell_to_move.col_idx = dest_col; AttributeError: can't set attribute` on `openpyxl 3.0.9` so inevitably something changed again.

Answer (score 2):

The following methods work for me, you can also specify a **different worksheet**:

```
from copy import copy

def copy_cell(source_cell, coord, tgt):
    tgt[coord].value = source_cell.value
    if source_cell.has_style:
        tgt[coord]._style = copy(source_cell._style)
    return tgt[coord]
```

You can call it with the following:

```
copy_cell(worksheet['E6'], 'D11', worksheet)
```

Or if you instead need to move a cell, you can do this:

```
def move_cell(source_cell, coord, tgt):
    tgt[coord].value = source_cell.value
    if source_cell.has_style:
        tgt[coord]._style = copy(source_cell._style)

    del source_cell.parent._cells[(source_cell.row, source_cell.col_idx)]

    return tgt[coord]
```

Nevertheless, notice that the merge cells have to be done separatedly.

Comment: It's quite an old question but appreciate your answer, it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in version `3.0.9`. Although, this **only** covers copying/moving **values and styling**.

```py
from copy import copy
from openpyxl.cell.cell import Cell
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def move_cell(cell: Cell, rows: int, cols: int, preserve_original=False) -> None:
    """Move ``cell`` by ``rows`` and ``cols``. If ``preserve_original`` is True, do copy instead
    of a move.

    .. note:: Anything already present in the new destination gets overwritten.
    """
    new_column = get_column_letter(cell.column + cols)
    new_cell = cell.parent[f"{new_column}{cell.row + rows}"]
    new_cell.value = cell.value
    if cell.has_style:
        new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
        new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
        new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
        new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
        new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
        new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
    if not preserve_original:
        cell.value = ""
        cell.style = "Normal"

def move_range(sheet: Worksheet, range_: str, rowscount: int, colscount: int,
               preserve_original=False) -> None:
    """Move range of cells defined by ``range_`` within the ``sheet`` by ``rowscount`` and
    ``colscount``.

    If ``preserve_original`` is True, this function does copy instead of a move (any overlapping
    gets overwritten).
    """
    for row in sheet[range_]:
        for cell in row:
            move_cell(cell, rowscount, colscount, preserve_original)
```