# Copy Complete Excel row with values, formatting, formulas etc

Tags: python, openpyxl

Well I've a row which i want to copy complete.
I dont know how i can do that correctly in python.

i try to copy the code from another stackoverflow page. But if i test the code i get errors

my own code is this.

```
# Copy input to output
output_table = input_table.copy()

# conda install -c anaconda openpyxl
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from copy import copy
from copy import deepcopy
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors, Color, PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection

def move_cell(source_cell, dest_row, dest_col, preserve_original=False):
    #param source_cell: cell to be moved to new coordinates
    #param dest_row: 1-indexed destination row
    #param dest_col: 1-indexed destination column
    #param preserve_original: if True, does a copy instead of a move
    if preserve_original:
        cell_to_move = copy.copy(source_cell)
    else:
        cell_to_move = source_cell
    worksheet = cell_to_move.parent
    source_address = (cell_to_move.row, cell_to_move.col_idx)
    dest_address = (dest_row, dest_col)
    
    cell_to_move.row = dest_row
    cell_to_move.col_idx = dest_col
    worksheet._cells[dest_address] = cell_to_move
    if not preserve_original:
        del worksheet._cells[source_address]
        
    return cell_to_move


var_data_path = "C:/"
#var_path_excel_file = var_data_path + os.path.sep + "data.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(var_path_excel_file)
ws = wb["test"]

# activate the ws 'data'
for s in range(len(wb.sheetnames)):
    if wb.sheetnames[s] == ws:
        break
wb.active = s

mr = ws.max_row 
mc = ws.max_column 
  
# copying the cell values from source  
# excel file to destination excel file 

for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
    c = ws.cell(row = 10, column = j)
    
    #ws.cells is my idea. But it don't copy the style and dont manipulate the formulas. i.e. =D10 to =D12 . Dependent from the row. Move cell function is the function which i copied from another great user. But i get errors for that. i test this all with the row 10. I want to copy the row 10 to 15.  My error is function' object has no attribute 'copy' Traceback (most recent call #last): File "<string>", line 85, in <module>
 # File "<string>", line 19, in move_cell
#AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'


ws.cell(15, column = j).value = c.value
    move_cell(c, 15, j, preserve_original=True)
    
#ws[15] = ws[10]
wb.save(var_path_excel_file)
```

[In openpyxl, how to move or copy a cell range with formatting, merged cells, formulas and hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347284/in-openpyxl-how-to-move-or-copy-a-cell-range-with-formatting-merged-cells-for/65147903#comment91502410_47609645)

Comment: do someone have a tip for me ?

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editing_worksheets.html

Comment: Well. The Link @CharlieClark didn't help. Because its only to move a row or to insert a new row. I want to copy a complete row with formulas, formats and values.

Comment: From the code it seems you want to do **both** move **and** copy.

Comment: @CharlieClark Well yeah. With this code is the possibility given to move and copy a row. But i want definitively copy a row with all features. value, formulas and formats. But my code is broken